# Remove complete document or element from array based on condition

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My collection documents are:

```
    {
      "_id" : 1,
      "fruits" : [ {"name":"pears"},
                   {"name":"grapes"},
                  {"name":"bananas"} ],
    }
    {
      "_id" : 2,
      "fruits" : [ {"name":"bananas"} ],
    }
```

I need to remove the whole document when the fruits contains only "bananas" or only remove the fruit "bananas" when there are more than one fruit in the fruits array.

My final collection after running the **required query** should be:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "fruits" : [ {"name":"pears"},
                   {"name":"grapes"}],
}
```

I am currently using two queries to get this done:

```
db.collection.remove({'fruits':{$size:1, $elemMatch:{'name': 'bananas'} }}) [this will remove the document when only one fruit present]
```

and

```
db.collection.update({},{$pull:{'fruits':{'name':'bananas'}}},{multi: true}) [this will remove the entry 'bananas' from the array]
```

Is there any way to combine these into **one query**?

**EDIT: Final take**

-- I guess there is no "one query" to perform the above tasks since the intents are very different of both the actions.

-- The best that can be performed is: club the actions into a bulk_write query which saves on the network I/O(as suggested in the answer by Neil). This is believe is more beneficial when you have multiple such actions being fired. Also, bulk_write can provide the feature of locking in the sense that the "ordered" mode of the bulk_write makes the actions sequential, breaking and halting execution in case of error.

Hence bulk_write is more beneficial when the actions performed need to be sequential. Somewhat like "chaining" in JS. There is also the option to perform un-ordered bulk_writes.

Also, the actions specified in the bulk write, operate on the `collection level as individual actions.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want [`bulk_write()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) here to do them both. Also Use [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to ensure there's only one element:

```
from pymongo import UpdateMany, DeleteMany

db.collection.bulk_write(
  [
   UpdateMany(
    { "fruits.1": { "$exists": True }, "fruits.name": "bananas" },
    { "$pull":{ 
      'fruits': { 'name':'bananas' }
    }}
   ),
   DeleteMany(
    { "fruits.1": { "$exists": False }, "fruits.name": "bananas" }
   )
  ],
  ordered=False
)
```

You don't really need [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for "one" condition and you should be using [`update_many()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) and in this case [`UpdateMany()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.UpdateMany) instead of `{ "multi": true }`. And that option is different in "pymongo" anyway. Then of course there is [`delete_many()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.delete_many) or [`DeleteMany()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.DeleteMany) for the "bulk" context.

Bulk operations send one request with one response, which is better than sending multiple requests. Also "update" and "delete" are two different things, but the single request can combine just like this.

The [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator is valid but [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) can apply to a "range" where [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) cannot, so it's generally a bit more flexible.

i.e Just as a [`$exists`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) range example

```
# Array between 2 and 4 elements
db.collection.update_many(
  { 
    "fruits.1": { "$exists": True },
    "fruits.4": { "$exists": False }, 
    "fruits.name": "bananas"
  },
  { "$pull":{ 
    'fruits': { 'name':'bananas' }
  }}
)
```

And of course in the context here you actually want to know the difference between other possible things in the array and those with "only" a single "bananas".

The `ordered=False` here actually refers to two different ways that "bulk write" requests can be handled

- **Ordered** - Where `True` ( which is the "default" ) then the operations are executed in "serial order" as they appear in the array of operations sent with the "bulk write". If any error occurs here then the batch stops execution at the point of the error and returns an exception.
- **UnOrdered** - Where `False` the operations are executed in "parallel" within reasonable constraints on the server. If any error occurs there is still an exception raised, however this does not stop other operations within the "bulk write" from completing. Any errors are returned with the "array index" from the list provided to the command of which operation caused the error.

This option can used to "tune" the desired behavior in particular to error reporting and continuation, and also allows a degree of "parallelism" to the execution where "serial" is not actually required of the operations. Since these two statements do not actually depend on one or the other and will in fact select different documents anyway, then `ordered=False` is probably the better option in terms of efficiency here.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.aggregate(
 [{
        $project: {
           data: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$fruits",
                    as: "filterData",
                    cond: { $ne: [ "$$filterData.name", 'bananas' ] }
                  }
                }
        }
    },
     {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$data",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false 
        }
    },
     {
        $group: {
        _id:"$_id",
        data: { $addToSet: "$data" }
        }
    },
])
```

I think above query would give you perfect results

Comment: The question is asking to "update" or "remove" the document. "from the collection". Aggregation does not do that.